# Changing format from %d/%m/%y to %Y-%m-%d in a csv file using AWK on Linux (UBUNTU)

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

I have hundreds of csv files with date format as %d / %m / %y  %H:%M:%S   but i want to change them to the format  %Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S

```
INPUT_FILE.csv (date format == %d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S )
13/05/87 4:00:00,1.27470,1.27530,1.27460,1.27480,101926,356
14/05/87 4:01:00,1.27490,1.27520,1.27310,1.27490,102419,493
15/05/87 4:02:00,1.27490,1.27540,1.27440,1.27530,102846,427
16/05/87 4:03:00,1.27520,1.27570,1.27490,1.27550,103202,356
17/05/87 4:04:00,1.27550,1.27640,1.27510,1.27590,103528,326
......
......
......
24/02/09 4:00:00,1.27470,1.27530,1.27460,1.27480,101926,356
25/02/09 4:01:00,1.27490,1.27520,1.27310,1.27490,102419,493
26/02/09 4:02:00,1.27490,1.27540,1.27440,1.27530,102846,427
27/02/09 4:03:00,1.27520,1.27570,1.27490,1.27550,103202,356
28/02/09 4:04:00,1.27550,1.27640,1.27510,1.27590,103528,326


REQUIRED_OUTPUT.csv   (date format == %Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S )

1987-05-13 4:00:00,1.27470,1.27530,1.27460,1.27480,101926,356
1987-05-14 4:01:00,1.27490,1.27520,1.27310,1.27490,102419,493
1987-05-15 4:02:00,1.27490,1.27540,1.27440,1.27530,102846,427
1987-05-16 4:03:00,1.27520,1.27570,1.27490,1.27550,103202,356
1987-05-17 4:04:00,1.27550,1.27640,1.27510,1.27590,103528,326
......
......
......   
2009-02-24 4:00:00,1.27470,1.27530,1.27460,1.27480,101926,356
2009-02-25 4:01:00,1.27490,1.27520,1.27310,1.27490,102419,493
2009-02-26 4:02:00,1.27490,1.27540,1.27440,1.27530,102846,427
2009-02-27 4:03:00,1.27520,1.27570,1.27490,1.27550,103202,356
2009-02-28 4:04:00,1.27550,1.27640,1.27510,1.27590,103528,326
```

I have tried a couple of AWK variations but i could not get it to work . any help

Update: my mistake , i should have mentioned that the dates or years  start from  **1981  to 2016**

here is what i have tried so far:

```
awk -F, '{ gsub("/","-");  split($1, f, " "); print >  ("my_data_" f[1]"v" ".csv")}' INPUT_FILE.csv
```

i get files split into e.g

```
my_data_13-05-87v.csv
my_data_14-05-87v.csv
my_data_15-05-87v.csv
```

with file contents as below

```
# for my_data_13-05-87v.csv
13-05-87 4:00:00,1.27470,1.27530,1.27460,1.27480,101926,356

# for my_data_14-05-87v.csv
14-05-87 4:01:00,1.27490,1.27520,1.27310,1.27490,102419,493

# for my_data_15-05-87v.csv
15-05-87 4:02:00,1.27490,1.27540,1.27440,1.27530,102846,427
```

NOTE: Years go from **1981 to 2016**

I want to split the files into e.g

```
my_data_1987-05-13v.csv
my_data_1987-05-13v.csv
my_data_1987-05-13v.csv
```

with file contents as below

```
# for my_data_1987-05-13v.csv
1987-05-13 4:00:00,1.27470,1.27530,1.27460,1.27480,101926,356

# for my_data_1987-05-14v.csv
1987-05-14 4:01:00,1.27490,1.27520,1.27310,1.27490,102419,493

# for my_data_1987-05-15v.csv
1987-05-15 4:02:00,1.27490,1.27540,1.27440,1.27530,102846,427
```

SECOND FORMAT QUESTION: 
I also have a different format

```
 INPUT_FILE.csv (date format == %d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S )
 13.05.1987 4:00:00.000,1.27470,1.27530,1.27460,1.27480,101926,356
 14.05.1987 4:01:00.000,1.27490,1.27520,1.27310,1.27490,102419,493
 15.05.1987 4:02:00.000,1.27490,1.27540,1.27440,1.27530,102846,427
 16.05.1987 4:03:00.000,1.27520,1.27570,1.27490,1.27550,103202,356
 17.05.1987 4:04:00.000,1.27550,1.27640,1.27510,1.27590,103528,326


 REQUIRED_OUTPUT.csv   (date format == %Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S )

 1987-05-13 4:00:00.000,1.27470,1.27530,1.27460,1.27480,101926,356
 1987-05-14 4:01:00.000,1.27490,1.27520,1.27310,1.27490,102419,493
 1987-05-15 4:02:00.000,1.27490,1.27540,1.27440,1.27530,102846,427
 1987-05-16 4:03:00.000,1.27520,1.27570,1.27490,1.27550,103202,356
 1987-05-17 4:04:00.000,1.27550,1.27640,1.27510,1.27590,103528,326
```

Comment: What happens next year?  Apart from you'll have passed, presumably, this course so you won't need to worry about it.  More generally, if you come across a date where the year is written 17, or 27, 37, 47, 57, 67, 77 — how should those dates be mapped in 2016, 2017, 2020, 2035, etc.?  There are multiple possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to redefine the input field separator to `/` and  and reorder the first three fields. Also, if the year field has a value `>16`, assume 20th century, otherwise 21st. And while at it, it writes the lines to files named per dates:

```
$ cat script.awk
{
    print ($3>16?"19":"20") $3 "-" $2 "-" $1, $4 > my_data_$1"-"$2"-"$3".csv"
}
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -F'[/ ]' -f script.awk INPUT_FILE.csv
```

Comment: This works for the Years in 20**  e.g 2009 , 2010 , etc but if the Year is 19** e.g 1985, 1990, etc  it fails

Comment: @JourneyMan Updated.

Comment: i need to be able to save the modifications as per the split files not to print them on the terminal. Take a look my awk script i tried using

Comment: how about a one-liner instead of scripts

Comment: Well, for this one its particularily to make the conversion. Add a pair of single quotes `'` around the script and remove newlines. `awk -F'[/ ]' '{print ($3>16?"19":"20") $3 "-" $2 "-" $1, $4 > my_data_$1"-"$2"-"$3".csv"}' INPUT_FILE.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach would be to use `substr`:

```
$ awk '{ $1 = sprintf("20%s-%s-%s",
                      substr($1, 7, 2),
                      substr($1, 4, 2),
                      substr($1, 1, 2))
       } 1' input.csv
2009-02-24 4:00:00,1.27470,1.27530,1.27460,1.27480,101926,356
2009-02-25 4:01:00,1.27490,1.27520,1.27310,1.27490,102419,493
2009-02-26 4:02:00,1.27490,1.27540,1.27440,1.27530,102846,427
2009-02-27 4:03:00,1.27520,1.27570,1.27490,1.27550,103202,356
2009-02-28 4:04:00,1.27550,1.27640,1.27510,1.27590,103528,326
```